# Django looking in wrong directory for templates

Tags: python, django

I followed a tutorial that taught to structure your templates directory as follows `~/project/main/templates/main` to avoid and confusion. Now I'm trying to create another project and use the same structure as good practice. I get a TemplateDoesNotExist error when trying to render html located at `/home/arch/project/main/templates/main/index.html` it says Django is looking in `/home/arch/project/templates/main/index.html`

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

main/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def homepage_view(request):
    return render(request, "main/index.html")
```

main/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homepage_view, name="homepage_view")
    ]
```

structure of my project

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── main
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── includes
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── media
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── static
```

Comment: What is `BASE_DIR`?

Comment: in `main` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @HenryM This was the problem. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your app is added in `INSTALLED_APPS`. I had this problem while trying Django for the first time.